# Code for generating an Access Token to the Camunda Console API REST client does not work

Tags: rest, curl, camunda

I'm trying to connect to the Camunda 8 Web platform through their API. I've already generated API keys for each service and downloaded the files given by Camunda. In the documentation (https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-tools/console-api-reference/), they say we can retrieve an access token via the following command:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --request POST \
    --data '{"grant_type":"client_credentials", "audience":"api.cloud.camunda.io", "client_id":"XXX", "client_secret":"YYY"}' \
    https://login.cloud.camunda.io/oauth/token
```

So, I replaced the client id and client secret placeholders with the values that I previously generated, but when I hit enter, nothing is returned.

I've looked on the documentation, but there's no mention of this behavior. Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?